# How to add !important to class

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, sass, bootstrap-modal

My drop down menu hides behind the modal(I am using bootstrap Modal) and I tried several ways to fix the problem but none of them works. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
id="ui-id-2" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 813px; left: 76px; width: 239px;">
<li>....</li>
</ul>
```

My autocomplete css is:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
border:1px solid #b2b8bd;
font-size: .750em;
max-height: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
z-index:9999;
}
```

However in my other scss file, I defined `$zindex-modal-background:  1040 !default;` and the definition for ui-front is

```
.ui-front {
z-index: $zindex-modal-background;}
```

It looks like the style ui-front overrides the autucomplete z-index. In my browser I have the following result:

[image]

I try to add !important to the z-index in ui-autocomplete but it looks like !important can't be applied to the class(only for id). I can't add id since there are many places using this drop down menu. Is there a way to make drop down menu shows on front of the modal?

Thanks

Comment: how you adding !important using the class? it works as usual not specific to id

Comment: Did you know if you want to use `z-index`, you have to set `position` too?

Answer (score 1):

`!important` should be the very last thing you reach for, if indeed you ever reach for it.

To make your rule override the other rule,

- Make your rule *more specific*. The two rules you've quoted have the same specificity. If it's just a class, add a tag to the rule as well, or a second class, or structural information, etc. Details on specificity calcuations are [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).
- Since the two rules have the same specificity, you can make your rule win by making sure it's *after* the other rule in the applied order of the CSS.